# Location of grafana.ini File

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I'm trying to configure email alerts through grafana and I'm unable to find the grafana.ini file. I followed [this](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/setup-grafana/installation/kubernetes/#deploy-grafana-enterprise-on-kubernetes) page to deploy a grafana instance on my local minikube setup and it works fine.

I'm just wondering how to access the grafana.ini file and modify it on minikube? I'm attempting to configure the smtp details in the grafana.ini file so I can send email alerts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your environment, configuring Grafana using environment variables instead of editing `grafana.ini` might be an easier option.

The environment variable pattern is the following: `GF_<SectionName>_<KeyName>`

E.g., to configure SMTP, one would edit the following environment variables:

```bash
# This is a bash script. In real life, you would
# probably add these environment variables in a .yaml file
# (e.g. docker-compose, Kubernetes deployment schema)
export GF_SMTP_ENABLED=true
export GF_SMTP_ENABLED=false
export GF_SMTP_HOST=localhost:25
export GF_SMTP_USER=
export GF_SMTP_PASSWORD=
export GF_SMTP_CERT_FILE=
export GF_SMTP_KEY_FILE=
export GF_SMTP_SKIP_VERIFY=false
export GF_SMTP_FROM_ADDRESS=admin@grafana.localhost
export GF_SMTP_FROM_NAME=grafana
export GF_SMTP_EHLO_IDENTITY=
export GF_SMTP_STARTTLS_POLICY=
```

**Useful links**

- [Configure Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/)
- [Default `grafana.ini`](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/main/conf/defaults.ini)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So I'm deploying grafana using the yaml here https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/setup-grafana/installation/kubernetes/#deploy-grafana-enterprise-on-kubernetes. Any idea where exactly I'd stick the environment variable? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: You can follow [this tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) to add environment variables to a Kubernetes container.

I would advise you to store sensitive environment variables in [Kubernetes Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) to store the environment variables, though. You can then [load them as environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables).

Comment: For anyone who lands here looking for the answer to the original question, on Linux try `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` or `/usr/local/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`.

Comment: This is great solution. Saved my couple of days